# Python can't find module 'clientsecrets' when trying to set up oauth2 in Django using the Google Python API

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I installed the `Google APIs Client Library for Python` on my `Windows 7` box using `pip`.   I am following the Django example that Google provides, but I can't start my server because Python throws an `ImportError: No module named 'clientsecrets'`.

I have verified that `clientsecrets.py` is located in `/path/to/python/Lib/site-packages`.

Any idea what could be causing this?  I am using `Python version 3.3.3` and `Django version 1.6.1`

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python running? can you confirm that by running the "python" command from the cmd prompt and seeing the default version?

Comment: @LearningNeverStops I only have Python `3.3.3` installed.

Comment: @LearningNeverStops Just verified when I got home, I am running the Python version `3.3.3` that definitely contains `clientsecrets.py` in `site-packages`.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed in */usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py* the line:

```
  22 import base64
  23 import clientsecrets
  24 import copy
```

to this:

```
  22 import base64
  23 import oauth2client.clientsecrets
  24 import copy
```

and then that solved that problem. This problem came only with Python 3, with Python 2.7 that worked out of box.