# import clientsecrets ImportError: No module named 'clientsecrets'

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I have installed google-api-python-client library using pip3.4 Iam following tutorial from google authenicating client library so every time i run the  python code provided by google to authenticate client library throws error as

```
     import clientsecrets ImportError: No module named 'clientsecrets'
```

I have only python3.4 running on my pc and no other python. it might be similar thread to one here [Python can't find module 'clientsecrets' when trying to set up oauth2 in Django using the Google Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521055/python-cant-find-module-clientsecrets-when-trying-to-set-up-oauth2-in-django) 
but i found no solution there.

The python code i got from google is here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/auth#authenticating_using_a_client_library

Answer (score 1):

The library doesn't support Python 3. As of [PEP 404](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/):

> In Python 3, implicit relative imports within packages are no longer available - only absolute imports and explicit relative imports are supported.

The `oauth2client` library uses `import clientsecrets`, which for Python 3 would need to be rewritten as `from . import clientsecrets`. Even if you changed those, the rest of the library would still be incompatible with Python 3.

There's at least one fork for Python 3 development, but it doesn't seem to be a big priority for the project. Until then, you'll have to find another library or write a wrapper yourself with `requests` for the functionality you need.

Comment: Note that oauth2client is said to support Python 3.3+ in [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2client/1.5.2), but I still have the same problem.